# Best way to recognise number drawn by user's finger on iPhone screen

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I'm planning on letting a user draw the shape of a number (1 to 9) in the shape of a 7-segment display. What is the best way to detect what number was drawn?

I know how to do all the touch-tracking and UIGestureRecogniser stuff - I'm looking for a good logic of doing it.

So far, I've got:
When a touch moves from 1 half of a segment to the other, highlight that seg. Once touches are finished, check what segs have been highlighted and decide what number drawn.

Ways I've thought of improving it:
Draw a shape of the finger's path on screen. If the line intersects the middle of a seg, highlight that seg.

Anyone got any tips or better ways of doing this? I'm open to any suggestion - even if it means scrapping all my code and starting from scratch.

Comment: It would seem you would need to have the user train the application first, so they would draw 0 - 9 a couple of times, you figure out how they do it, then they do it where you are trying to determine the number.  Good luck.

Comment: Do you have to use this segment technique? This would probably be perfect for some neural network to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try the neural network idea out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used implementations of the $ stroke recognizers for drawn number recognition.

- [$1 Unistroke recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/)
- [$N Multistroke recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html)

Both algorithms link to several Objective-C / iOS implementations.

The recognizers will compare input against predefined patterns based on different algorithms (detailed explanation available on the linked pages). For this to work you'll have to make your own number patterns (basically just draw something and let the recognizer convert this to a data structure you store for later use). Then on user input compare to the patterns you recorded earlier to find a match.

The $1 recognizer was sufficient for my application where I would let the user train first to practice drawing the numbers. The $N recognizer is able to distinguish between more complex stokes and might accept more complex drawn numbers. This is something you will have to experiment with.

Comment: Thanks very much for that info. Sadly, the first obj-c project link for the $1 recognizer is broken, but there are others that I'll try as soon as I can!

Comment: Tried this one today: https://github.com/preble/GLGestureRecognizer . Glad to say it works WONDERFULLY. Thanks again for the fantastic link!

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in detecting the numbers 1-9, check out [BGNumericalGlyphRecognizer](https://github.com/bengotow/BGNumericalGlyphRecognizer). I spent several months working with an $N-multistroke recognizer to create ScribbleMath (a math app that allows kids to draw their answers on the screen) and open-sourced the core logic. It turns out $N recognizers have a hard time differentiating 6 and 9, and are also bad at recognizing very simple letters like 1 and "-", and I created logic for handling those better. It's not perfect, but it'll get you farther than an $N recognizer out of the box. Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any similar repository like this one ? I am working with swift.

Comment: I am trying to use this in swift but getting this error. /GestureDigit/WTMGlyph/WTMGlyphStroke.m:27:37: No known class method for selector 'valueWithCGPoint:' Any idea ?

Comment: Excuse me I have some problems opening the git project. you wote I should open terminal in mac os and then cd to the top. what do you mean by `and cd to the top level directory of the repository` .

Comment: I fetch update with the help of github desktop. but the problem is that it still have some errors with this topic `Use of undeclared identifier 'self'` in the codes